# How to call parent method from base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, methods, parent-child

How do I ideally call a method from the parent class in my base class:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def addhalf(self):
        self.counter = self.counter + 0.5

class base(parent):
    def subhalf(self):
        # Option 1:
        parent.addhalf(self)
        # Option 2:
        self.addhalf()
        self.counter = self.counter - 1
```

What is the difference between these two options?

Comment: `self.addhalf()`? Then if another class is added to the hierarchy, you don't need to change `subhalf`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for editing the question. I'm not sure if I understand your reply. Can you elaborate on it? In which case would I need to change subhalf?

Comment: Imagine adding a third class, such that `class mid(parent):` and `class base(mid):`. If you use the `self` form it doesn't matter whether or not `mid` has its own implementation of `addhalf` or not. If you refer to it directly on `parent`, you're more coupled to the details.

Comment: ok, got it. So I use option 1 if I want to use explicitly ```addhalf``` of the ```parent``` class and option 2 if I want to use the ```addhalf``` that is valid for my base class

Comment: You will want to know about `super()` too. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super)